# URL structure for template

Tags: ee2, ee

I can't understand how to made URL structure for page
For eg

http://site.com/template_group/temlate1/template2/template3

http://site.com/services/cleaning/reviews/best

In admin panel, at template group services
we have 4 templates

*index
cleaning
reviews
best*

Every template have url

http://site.com/services/index/

http://site.com/services/cleaning/

http://site.com/services/reviews/

http://site.com/services/best/

I need to display some templates like this

http://site.com/services/cleaning/reviews/

or

http://site.com/services/cleaning/reviews/best/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important that you understand how EE parses URLs to determine what to display.

Generally it goes like this:

```
template-group/template/entry
```

or

```
template-group/template/category-trigger-word/category-id
```

The way you described your setup you seem to want to show two templates from the services channel at once (cleaning and reviews). Clearly this can't be done.

There are a number of ways to do what you want:

#### Using EE's native parsing

Set up your template group, "services". Then create your "cleaning" template.
Within this template you can place a conditional which looks at the third URL segment ({segment_3}) and will then output the required reviews content. This might be done directly on the template, or by means of an embedded template.

#### Use the Pages module

The pages module is really meant for the occasional static page but you could use it for this. It will allow you to set a custom URL for an entry and also choose which template should be used to render it.

#### Use Template Routes

Template routes are very powerful and will let you set up different URLs to load specific templates. Within the route you can include rules to make sure your segments are a particular type.

#### Use an add-on such as Structure

Love it or hate it but Structure can be extremely useful for some sites. This may be the simplest solution for you but be warned, it can bring it's own problems too.

Comment: Thank you! What about example?